# How do I identify typescript code while looking at it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, identification

I've been seeing some code that looks like js but fails in console. It is typescript, and the referencee hasn't explicitly said that the code is indeed 'typescript'. So, what are the immediate signs that some piece of code is typescript? I know if I execute it in the console it is likely to fail, but what visual parsing shortcuts can I use?
I've noticed the semicolon is rather ubiquitous in typescript.
`function logger(message: string) {`

parameter type info

`function logger(message: string) : returntype {`

Comment: for that you need to learn typescript

Comment: Learning typescript is a long shortcut.

Comment: you can look at the file extension it will be file.ts rather than file.js. For details you need to learn typescript, you can search for a typescript crash course on youtube and you will find an hour crash course that will be enough to identify typescript code.

Comment: The scientist says 'we need more research'. I was thinking number of semicolons as proportion of text as a mark of how typescripty something is.

Comment: So, I've put 1000 pieces of code which were exactly 1000 characters long, including newlines and spaces - vertical, horizontal, non-breaking, unicode format and found that the magic number is 25%. Typescript has 25% more semicolons.

Comment: Code in a `.js` file should not contain TypeScript syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same thing.

Here are a couple ways to recognize TypeScript code:

**Type annotations**
TypeScript introduces static types, which allow you to annotate your variables, function parameters, function return values, object properties, etc. with types. This can help catch errors early and improve code readability and maintainability. For example, `let x: number = 3;` is TypeScript because of the `: number` type annotation. You are literally telling the compiler "x can only be a number, if I make it something else, throw an error".

**Generics**
Generics allow you to write reusable code that can work over a variety of types. Javascript doesn't have generics since it is dynamically typed. If you see something like `Array<number>` or `Promise<string>`, that's a use of generics and indicates that the code is TypeScript.

**Interfaces and types**
TypeScript allows you to define your own types using interface and type keywords. For example, `interface User { name: string; age: number; }` is TypeScript.

**Access modifiers**
TypeScript supports public, private, and protected access modifiers on class properties and methods, something that JavaScript doesn't natively support.
If you see something like:

```
class Employee {
    private name: string;
    public age: number;
    protected position: string;
```

**Enums**
Javascript doesn't use enums. TypeScript supports enumerated types (enums), which are a way of giving more friendly names to sets of numeric values. It is Typescript if you see something like this:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

let myColor: Color = Color.Green;
```

Remember, TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, which means that all valid JavaScript code is also valid TypeScript code. But if you want to use Typescript, you have to use a compiler, which will transform it into Javascript.

TypeScript just adds additional features on top of JavaScript.